# Store values from a JSON file into variables

Tags: json, swift, swift4

I've been trying for hours to read values from a JSON file in the app bundle and print those values. I've been scouring several forums and SO questions trying to piece together a way to read from a .json file, but have had no luck. What I currently have is a bunch of (probably useless) code that looks like this:

```
//json parsing
        if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "POIs", ofType: "json") {
            do {
                let data = try Data(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: path), options: .mappedIfSafe)
                let jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableLeaves)
                if let jsonResult = jsonResult as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject>, let pois = jsonResult["POI"] {

                    print("test ", pois)
                    for poi in pois as! [AnyObject] {
                        guard let name = poi["name"], //String
                            let coordinatesJSON = poi["coordinates"] as? [String: Double],
                            let latitudeVar = coordinatesJSON["lat"],
                            let longitudeVar = coordinatesJSON["lng"],
                            let altitude = poi["altitude"], //Int
                            let facebookurl = poi["facebookurl"], //String
                            let poiImage = poi["pinImage"] //String
                        else {
                            return
                        }
```

and my POIs.json file looks like this:

```
{
"POI":[
        {
            "name": "Boston Paintball",
            "coordinates": {
                "lat": 42.401848,
                "lng": -71.023843
            },
            "altitude": 7,
            "facebookurl": "https://www.facebook.com/PlayBostonPaintball/",
            "pinImage": "bp"
        },
        {
            "name": "Chilis",
            "coordinates": {
                "lat": 42.402314,
                "lng": -71.021655
            },
            "altitude": 7,
            "facebookurl": "https://www.facebook.com/chilis",
            "pinImage": "chilis"
        }
    ]
}
```

Can anyone show me the best way to read values from a json, store them into the variables I specified, and then print them? Thank you!

UPDATED CODE:

```
//json parsing
        let file = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "POIs", withExtension: "json")
        let data = try? Data(contentsOf: file!)
        let root = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Root.self, from: data!)

        do {
            let root = try JSONDecoder().decode(Root.self, from: data!)
            print(root)
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }

        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        let pois = try? decoder.decode([Root].self, from: data!)

        let pinUIImage = UIImage(named: Location.pinImage)
```

But still giving me a `Instance member 'pinImage' cannot be used on type 'ViewController.Location'` error.

UPDATE 2:

```
for poi in (root?.pointsOfInterest)! {
            if let location = root?.pointsOfInterest.??? { //I dont know how to grab the poi from the current iteration. Any tips?
```

Comment: I would recommend using swiftyjson for this. It makes your code a lot cleaner. There is also codeable that apple just released in swift 4 but I feel that there is still some work that apple needs to do before it becomes as easy to use as swiftyjson is.

Comment: If you articulate which variable you are looking to print and how you want them formatted, I can show you how it is done using swiftyjson.

Comment: @NevinJethmalani Dont recommend using something that it is already outdated

Comment: why do you say swiftyjson is outdated? what would you recommend?

Comment: Codable protocol

Comment: I have tried using codable but there are a bunch of issues I had when using it. Can it do everything that swiftyjson does as easily?

Answer (score 1):

You should structure your data to conform to Codable protocol:

```
struct Root: Codable {
    let pointsOfInterest: [Location]
    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case pointsOfInterest = "POI"
    }
}
struct Location: Codable {
    let name: String
    let coordinates: Coordinate
    let altitude: Int
    let facebookurl: String
    let pinImage: String
}
struct Coordinate: Codable {
    let latitude: Double
    let longitude: Double
    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case latitude = "lat", longitude = "lng"
    }
}
```

---

```
do {
    let root = try JSONDecoder().decode(Root.self, from: jsonData)
    print(root)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

This will print

> Root(pointsOfInterest: [__lldb_expr_39.Location(name: "Boston
>   Paintball", coordinates: __lldb_expr_39.Coordinate(latitude:
>   42.401848000000001, longitude: -71.023842999999999), altitude: 7, facebookurl: "https://www.facebook.com/PlayBostonPaintball/",
>   pinImage: "bp"), __lldb_expr_39.Location(name: "Chilis", coordinates:
>   __lldb_expr_39.Coordinate(latitude: 42.402313999999997, longitude: -71.021654999999996), altitude: 7, facebookurl: "https://www.facebook.com/chilis", pinImage: "chilis")])

Comment: what if the lat and long was returned as a string but we want them to be a Double in the struct, how would we do that? This is one of the problems I was having with codable.

Comment: You can just store it as a String and create a computed property to return a double

Comment: Please excuse the dumb question, but how does this code know where to open the json file from? I dont see a reference to POIs.json anywhere in this snippit. Can you explain this to me? Thanks!

Comment: Just use the `data` that you are reading from the url or the data that comes from the server instead of `jsonData`

Comment: Btw instead of getting the path you should use Bundle's url method to get the url.  `Bundle.main.url(forResource: "POIs", withExtension: "json")`

Comment: Hi, so I'm getting closer, now I'm getting an error on this snippt:
`guard let file = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "POIs", withExtension: "json") else {
            throw("no file")
        }
`



`Error is not handled because the enclosing function is not declared 'throws'`

Comment: from this guide: https://chaione.com/blog/swift-4-jsonencoder-jsondecoder-extensions/

Comment: Getting this error: `Instance member 'pinImage' cannot be used on type 'ViewController.Location'` when trying to access the image with this code: `let pinImage = UIImage(named: Location.pinImage)`. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: @Alan What is "chilis" ? Is it the name of an image in your Assets? Note that you should be using `location` lowercased which it is an instance of Location. `location.pinImage`

Comment: it is the name of an image asset. Let me try it with the lowercased "location"

Comment: When I do a lowercase `location`, it says it's unresolved and asks me if i want to fix it to `Location`

Comment: Updated question with current code. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: @Alan you need to get an element (location) from your root object which contains the property pointsOfInterest (array of locations)

Comment: I dont know how many locations you are getting from the api so you might need to iterate over the locations (pointsOfInterest) instead of getting only the first element

Comment: Awesome, so now it at least compiles. I will update my question with one more problem I have. I'm having issues grabbing the correct element of the array of locations. I have it in a for loop, but I don't know the keyword to pick the correct location while iterating. It (obviously) only grabs the first element when I do `if let location = root.pointsOfInterest.first`, but I want to know how to make it grab the element that it is iterating through. Please take a look at my updated question. I feel like I'm getting very close. Thanks again!!